# BroadcastReceiver or GCMBroadcastReceiver for Google Cloud Messaging client?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

in the documentation, about writing the Android part for Google Cloud Messaging, two different options are described:

-using `com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar`, `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver` and `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService` in  http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app

-using `android.content.BroadcastReceiver` and `android.app.IntentService` + writing the handlers in http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#writing_apps.

This is confusing. What's the recommended way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I trust Commonsware, I checked in his [Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development](http://commonsware.com/Android/) and used com.google.android.gcm.GCM* classes. They make everything easier (save registration to preferences, make use of wakelock...).

Answer (score 1):

-using

> com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar,
>   com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver and
>   com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService

in http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app

works well here